What does Kant mean by pure intuitions, and why are they not separate from the faculty of sensibility?
Please note: I am not a student of philosophy and am learning it on my own. I've certainly made mistakes here; please correct me.
As I understand it, Kant proposes that objects are presented to the mind via representations, of which there are two classes: intuitions (a concrete representation of an object, i.e. a tree as experienced) and concepts (an abstract representation of an object, i.e. the concept of a tree). Kant classes intuitions as either pure (a priori, provides the form of a structured intuition, i.e. space and time) or empirical (a posteriori, provides the content of a structured intuition).
My understanding is that the role of the faculty of sensibility is the structuring of empirical intuitions using the pure intuitions (space and time) to produce structured intuitions (not a term that Kant uses, just what I use to clarify the concepts). These structured intuitions are then conceptualised (e.g. have concepts applied to them) by the faculty of understanding. (Then, the faculty of reason is responsible for the systemisation and unity of knowledge via principles.)
If we suppose that "intuition" is defined as a concrete representation of an object, it makes sense to me why an empirical intuition is a form of intuition. It does not, however, make sense to me why pure intuitions are a form of intuition. If space and time are applied to intuitions for structure, why are they themselves a form of intuition? Why are they not categories that allow for the coherence and structure of knowledge? (I have not yet studied the Transcendental Dialectic, so this may be where the problem is).
To be precise, why are pure intuitions at all, rather than categories of understanding? What defines space and time as intuitions rather than categories? Which definition of an "intuition" unifies experience (empirical intuitions, i.e. a tree) and the conditions for experience (pure intuitions, i.e. space and time)?
It seems to me a chaotic system for sensibility (the faculty of intuition) to apply one form of intuition (pure) to another form of intuition to produce coherent experience.
Which of Kant's theories am I misunderstanding?
EDIT: My initial post was long and circuitious, so I am going to try to make my question more clear

Intuitions are sensory representations of objects.
Pure Intuitions are a priori representation
Space and time are pure intuitions
Empirical Intuitions are a posteriori representations

I understand the concept of intuitions.
I understand why empirical intuitions are called intuitions: they are immediate representations of sensory information.
I understand that space and time are a priori, as we cannot conceive of experience outside of space and/or time. I believe Kant provides quite a few arguments for the necessity of space and time as a priori conditions for experience.
What I do not understand, however, is why space and time are intuitions. I understand why they are pure, as they are not derived from experience. As I understand it, they are not "sensory representations"; space and time do not exist in the same way that, say, a tree does. They are also not "objects", so fail to meet the definition of an intuition.

I recommend to read Kant's own words, e.g., to read the preface to the second edition of the Critique of Pure Reason, see https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4280/pg4280-images.html#chap02

As I have no background in philosophy, I am ever so aware of the risks of reading philosophy without supportive material. As an example, Ayn Rand's criticism of Kant can be attributed to misinterpretation of his words, rather than any true salient criticism of Kant's philosophy. Another example is Jordan Peterson's view of Nietzsche (and postmodernism). I am not trying to negate the importance of primary texts; however, as I don't have access to teachers and professors of philosophy, my plan is to establish knowledge via secondary sources, and consolidate via primary sources.

Space and time are not pure intuitions in the narrow sense of concrete representations (like mathematical triangles are), they are forms of intuition that enable both them and empirical intuitions. There are no two forms of intuition, the same sensibility is operative in empirical and pure contexts, hence empirical applicability of pure mathematics. And space and time are not categories because they do not operate conceptually, what we can do synthetically in space exceeds conceptual capabilities. As Kant shows with isosceles triangles, pons asinorum does not follow conceptually.

I can only imagine how easy it would be to misinterpret the technical language used by philosophers by applying the colloquial definitions to them (Sensibility, Understanding, Spirit/Mind/Geist, ).

Excellent question. I've always found that part of Kant's work a little confusing. I can see why they aren't concepts (they aren't abstract) but I don't see how they are intuitions of any kind.

@DavidGudeman - not easy... see Kant’s understanding of representation: we have sensation that Kant "regards not as a representation of an object, property, event, etc., but merely as a state of the subject [the pain in the finger caused by a needle: there is no "pain" in the niddle that is "represented" in the finger], while intuition as a conscious, objective representation. 1/2

If we felt only sensations, we would lack representations of things other than ourselves, even if such things caused or helped to cause our sensations. Without intuition, we would lack spatial awareness: that is, we would lack an awareness of things in spatial locations around us. In order to represent things other than ourselves, we require intutition, which Kant regards as a singular, immediate, objective representation (where sensations are merely subjective, as we have seen)." 2/2

"If we suppose that "intuition" is defined as a concrete representation of an object..." Correct, see SEP's schema: intuition is on the "objective" side vs sensation that is on the subjective side. But intuition is of objects (particulars) vs the concept side. Categories are on the concept side, while space and time are peculiar: they are not concepts (universals predicated of objects) and neither objects (we see houses located in space, but not "empty space"; we are aware of events in time, but not "empty time").

See also What is "intuition" for Kant? as well as How is 'Pure Intuition' possible according to Kant?

Pure intuition is still intuition which cannot be separated from the faculty of sensibility...

Why the forms of intuition must be associated with sensibility while the categories are with understanding
The form of intuition, in Aristotelean tradition, has to be understood as opposed to its matter. Kant holds that for us to be able to have an intuition of a particular object, may it be empirical or purely geometrical, it has to be represented in space and time. Only in space and time, these objects of intuition will be objects for us, ie. something our mind can work with.
The categories, in turn, are needed to understand (subsume) these particular objects of intuition under concepts to apprehend them in relation to other objects of intuition, ie. their specifics and thus their being as a thing.
In a way, one could say that sensibility/intuition just presents a this, while understanding enables us to apprehend that mere this as some particular thing with certain properties. Kant later, at the end of the Dialectics, admits that the differentiation between the functions of sensibility and understanding is a bit artificial but it still helps to keep them apart since the functional import is different.
In which way are space and time themselves intuitions?
Space and time do, to the confusion of many a Kant student and scholar, occur in at least three forms in Kant's work:

As forms of intuition
As pure intuitions
As empirical intuitions

In the latter case, it is quite simple: we can experience time and space in daily life. The room you are in is empirical space and the time you need to read these words is experienced. I guess your confusion relates to the first two.
Now, why can we call the forms of intuition "pure intuitions" (since that's how we have to look at this)?
Well, if we concede that space and time are the forms of every intuition, when we do an abstraction from any matter (content) of the intuition, the "pure" (a priori, not empirical) rest that remains are two distinct aspects of any this: space (space-ness) and time (time-ness). They still are "intuition", since what else should they be? while they are not part of the empirical manifold, hence they are two distinct "pure intuitions".
Everything hinges at whether we concede that space and time are necessary forms of intuition. If we do, as often with Kant, it is hard to cop-out at a later stage of the argument.

I believe I understand the point you are making, with regards to why space and time belong to the faculty of sensibility, rather than to understanding or reason. However, I don't think that it cuts to the core of my confusion. My original post was a bit all-over-the-place; the heart of my confusion right now is why space and time are intuitions specifically. I understand the necessity of them being part of the faculty of sensibility. However, in my mind they do not cohere to the definition of intuition (sensory representation of an object).

I understand why space and time are a priori, just not why they are intuitions. I understand (thanks to your post) why they belong to the faculty of sensibility. I am just uncertain of the common essence between pure intuitions (space/time) and empirical intuitions. What characteristics/properties do they share, to be classed in the same group?.

@BithovVinu Do my additional remarks help to untangle your confusion?

OP: "It does not, however, make sense to me why pure intuitions are a form of intuition. If space and time are applied to intuitions for structure, why are they themselves a form of intuition? Why are they not categories that allow for the coherence and structure of knowledge?"
Heidegger's interpretation of Kant identifies the intuition of time as part of the self, not separate or incidental (as affecting).

Time as pure self-affection is that finite, pure intuition which
sustains and makes possible the pure concept (the understanding) as
that which is essentially at the service of intuition.
Hence, it is not in the second edition that Kant first introduces the
idea of pure self-affection, which last, as has now become clear,
determines the innermost essence of transcendence. It is simply that
the idea is formulated more explicitly in this edition and,
characteristically enough, appears [at the beginning of the work] in
the transcendental aesthetic.87 To be sure, this passage
must remain obscure as long as the interpretation lacks that
perspective assured by the more primordial comprehension of the laying
of the foundation of metaphysics made possible by the preceding
presentation of the stages of this foundation. But given this
perspective, the passage is almost "self-evident."
"Now that which, as representation, can be antecedent to any and every
act of thinking anything, is intuition; and if it contains nothing but
relations, it is the form of intuition. Since this form does not
represent anything save insofar as something is posited in the mind,
it can be nothing but the mode in which the mind is affected through
its own activity (namely, through this positing of [their]
representation), and so is affected by itself; in other words, it is
nothing but an inner sense in respect of the form of that sense."
88
"Sense" means "finite intuition." The form of sense, therefore, is
pure receptivity. The internal sense does not receive "from without"
but from the self. In pure receptivity, internal affection must arise
from the pure self, i.e., be formed in the essence of selfhood as
such, and therefore must constitute the latter. Pure self-affection
provides the transcendental ground-structure [Urstruktur] of the
finite self as such. Therefore, it is absolutely untrue that the mind
exists in such a way that, among other beings, it relates certain
things to itself and in so doing posits itself [Selbstsetzungen
ausübt]. Rather, this line of orientation from the self toward . . .
and back to [the self] first constitutes the mental character of the
mind as a finite self.
It is at once obvious, therefore, that
time as pure self-affection is not found "in the mind" "beside" pure
apperception. On the contrary, as the basis of the possibility of
selfhood, time is already included in pure apperception and first
enables the mind to be what it is.
The pure finite self has in itself a temporal character. Therefore, if
the ego, i.e., pure reason, is essentially temporal, the fundamental
determination which Kant provides for transcendental apperception must
first become intelligible through this temporal character.
Time and the "I think" are no longer opposed to one another as unlike
and incompatible; they are the same. Thanks to the radicalism with
which, in the laying of the foundation of metaphysics, Kant for the
first time subjected time and the "I think," each taken separately, to
a transcendental interpretation, he succeeded in bringing them
together in their primordial identity — without, to be sure, having
seen this identity expressly as such. Kantbuch 195-7


Pure sensibility (time) and pure reason are not only homogeneous,
they belong together in the unity of the same essence which makes
possible the finitude of human subjectivity in its totality.
Ibid. 201

Space does not seem to be an equal intuition to time in Heidegger's scheme.  The fundamental is Being-in-the-world in which time is bound up with being (and reason), then space is discovered.  Curious because being-in-the-world implies some spaciality.

Only on the basis of its ecstatico-horizonal temporality is it possible for Dasein to break into space. The world is not
present-at-hand in space; yet only within a world does space let
itself be discovered. Being & Time 421

It's probably prudent to mention how Heidegger sees ordinary, clock-time.  This is distinct from the temporality of the self.

The measurement of time gives it a marked public character, so that
only in this way does what we generally call 'the time' become well
known. ... That time 'wherein' entities within-the-world are
encountered, we know as "world-time". By reason of the
ecstatico-horizonal constitution of the temporality which belongs to
it, this has the same transcendence as the world itself. Ibid.
471


First, I want to clarify a few concepts: an intuition is a singular, immediate and sensible representation (=any content that may be present to consciousness): in other words, we can define it as a many-in-one structured representational consciousness in which manifolds of appearances are originally apprehended. Kant will argue that any intuition, in beings constituted like us, is sensible (as opposed to intellectual), and can be classified in two types: pure (a priori) and empirical (a posteriori). If an intuition involves the consciousness of particular sensations (that occur when something external affects the mind), then it counts as empirical, and it gives us an indeterminate object (appearance); while if it involves the presence of sensations but no consciousness of particular sensational contents, then it is a priori, or pure. Kant will argue that, for us, these pure intuitions are space and time.
So, let's go back a bit: remember that empirical intuitions give us appearances (indeterminate objects)? These appearances have a twofold composition: they have both a matter (the physical realities indicated by sensation) and a form (space and time). This is what Kant means when he says that space and time are forms of appearances: space and time cognitively determine the matter of appearances according to certain relations. In other words, we don't apply the forms of space and time to empirical intuitions: rather, space and time are a condition of possibility for us to have any intuition/appearance.
Moreover, Kant will also argue that space and time are not only forms of appearances, but are themselves (pure) intuitions, because they are also given as indeterminate (and infinite, he will argue) objects; but they count as pure because they don't involve consciousness of any particular sensational content, like I said above. Therefore, they  meet all the criteria to be classified as intuitions: singularity, since they are essentially one, and contain all other spaces and times within them, as individuals; immediacy, since they are not mediated by concepts; and presence of sensations.
